# Where Is Facebook API Throttling Data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, throttling

In Facebook API insights 1.0 it provided throttling warnings data that showed which calls you were making that was using the most data and which were the most CPU intensive. This data was helpful in optimizing your calls to prevent exceeding the rate limit But insights 2.0 does not provide this data. My app gets throttled every few days and blocked for about an hour every time. But I do not have the data to figure out which calls are causing this, like I did with insights 1.0 . How can I get the API throttling data?

Comment: does your app respond to user events or loop constantly to pull data ?

Comment: @damian nikodem it responds to user events.

Comment: are you making bulk calls? or are you performing multiple calls (or even worse multiple reauthentications) for each user event ?

Comment: @damian nikodem I am making batch calls.

Comment: and what is your userbase look like ? Could a web spider be crawling something it can find and causing the throttle?

Comment: @damian nikodem 90% of my website can be used without the user having to login, so if they are not logged I then the calls use an app token. When they are logged in then it uses user token. I get about 6500 visitors per day and but my monthly registered users is only 1000. Yes Google crawls 1000s of my pages every day. I slowly increase the Google crawl rate as I get more more registered users since app rate limit depends on how many monthly registered users. I already tried decreasing Google crawl rate a few days ago but my app just got throttled again today and was down for an hour.

Comment: And I don't want to decrease Google crawl rate too much because 95% of my traffic cones from Google search